# Can someone help me understand what is actually going on in the appendChild method?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<blockquote id="quote">
    No book can ever be finished. While working on it we learn
    just enough to find it immature the moment we turn away
    from it.
</blockquote>

<script>
    function elt(type) {
        var node = document.createElement(type);
        for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            var child = arguments[i];
            if (typeof child == "string")
                child = document.createTextNode(child);
            node.appendChild(child);
        }
        return node;
    }

    document.getElementById("quote").appendChild(
        elt("footer", "—",
            elt("strong", "Karl Popper"),
            ", preface to the second editon of ",
            elt("em", "The Open Society and Its Enemies"),
            ", 1950"
        )
    );
</script>
```

Can someone help me understand what is actually going on in the `appendChild` method in

> document.getElementById("quote").appendChild(elt(...));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `elt` function takes a parameter of `type`, which is the type of element to be created (see `elt("footer")`). It also processes an unspecified number of arguments; for each argument that is a string, it creates a `textNode` that contains that string.

The `appendChild` method is simply calling the `elt` method with, in your example, one argument, which is a function call (`elt()`), and *that* function call contains six arguments, two of which are `elt()` function calls—each of which contains two arguments, both of which are strings.

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: How does the elt() know which argument is the _type_.? There are two arguments when the function is called. @Nimmo

Comment: "type" is the only parameter it is expecting, so it will see the first argument passed to it as "type". However, every function in JavaScript has access to any arguments that it is called with, regardless of the number of parameters specified in the function itself, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: thanks for your reply. I checked the output by swapping the parameters passed to elt () and it showed up an  error. So this solves my doubt. Thumbs up for your help

Answer (score 0):

The elt call contains 6 arguments, in which two of the arguments are elt() function calls. As "strong" and "em" will be the child elements of footer the order of the elt function execution is as follows.

First elt function build child elements by calling `elt("strong", "Karl Popper")`

and `elt("em", "The Open Society and Its Enemies")`

And finally the `elt("footer", "-", remaining arguments..)` function gets called with 6 agrugments. As the two child node were created it will append the text "--" and ", preface to the second editon of," and "1950" and build the whole text.

Please free to comment if I miss anything.

Comment: How does the elt() know which argument passed while calling it is the _type_ argument? @Ramu